# What's is the restrictions for the function MatrixExp?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

When I use the *MatrixExp* on a general $2\times2$ matrix, *Mathematica*
gives me this result:

```
MatrixExp[{{a,b},{c,d}}] // TraditionalForm
```

$\frac{1}{2\triangle}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{\frac{\triangle+a+d}{2}}\left(\triangle+a-d\right)-e^{\frac{-\triangle+a+d}{2}}\left(-\triangle+a-d\right) & 2be^{\frac{\triangle+a+d}{2}}-2be^{\frac{-\triangle+a+d}{2}}\\
2ce^{\frac{\triangle+a+d}{2}}-2ce^{\frac{-\triangle+a+d}{2}} & e^{\frac{\triangle+a+d}{2}}\left(\triangle-a+d\right)-e^{\frac{-\triangle+a+d}{2}}\left(-\triangle-a+d\right)
\end{array}\right)$

where $\triangle=\sqrt{a^{2}-2ad+4bc+d^{2}}$

Is this true for any matrix  {{a,b},{c,d}} (including complex matrix)?
If it is not, what is the restrictions on the matrix {{a,b},{c,d}}?

Comment: from help `works only on square matrices`. So as long as the matrix is square, it will work.

Comment: I found this requirement from help also, it's a weak even strange requirement. I guess there exist more restrictions on the matrix if we are interested in complex matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all variables in *Mathematica* are assumed complex, and **generic** results are calculated if you don't specify any restrictions, e.g., with `Assumptions`.

So the above result is generically true for complex matrices. **But** it's not true for non-generic matrices, where some elements have special values. For example, take

```
MatrixExp[{{a,b},{c,d}}]/.{c->0,d->a}
```

which gives errors. You would have to calculate such specific cases separately:

```
MatrixExp[{{a, b}, {0, a}}]

(* ==> {{E^a, b E^a}, {0, E^a}} *)
```

Comment: Specifically, it will fail for specialized values that make the Jordan decomposition non-generic.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry, I don't understand your comment, could you please give me a example to digest?

Comment: Jens provided a very explicit example. The Jordan matrix for `{{a,b},{c,d}}` has two distinct eigenvalues and no ones over the main diagonal. For the special form {{a,b},{0,a}}` it has a repeated eigenvalue (`a`), and a nontrivial Jordan block, that is, a 1 over the diagonal.

Comment: May I conclude as following:
"The formula posted here is true only when the matrix is diagonalizable and has 2 different eigenvalues. And the function *MatrixExp* always gives the correct result" ?

Comment: I don't think the eigenvalues even need to be distinct. I think it just needs to be diagonalizable. So the "only" in the statement above is not quite right.

Comment: The eigenvalues of the matrix are $\lambda_{\pm}=\frac{\left(a+d\right)\pm\sqrt{a^{2}-2ad+4bc+d^{2}}}{2}$. When two eigenvalues meet, we get $\triangle=\sqrt{a^{2}-2ad+4bc+d^{2}}=0$, where $\triangle$ is the common denominator of the formula. Thus the formula fails for this case.